# How to use iOS Masonry (Auto Layout) to position two buttons next to each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, masonry-ios-osx

I am updating a screen which initially had one button at the bottom. My task is to render two buttons centered at the bottom using Masonry framework which is an AutoLayout wrapper.

I would like to have the two buttons centered at the bottom and side by side. This is what I've come up with:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
- (void)createConstraints {

    // Map View
    [self.mapView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.left.and.right.equalTo(self);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.mas_centerY).multipliedBy(0.9);
    }];

    // Information TextView
    [self.informationTextView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(self.mapView.mas_bottom); //.with.offset(kTableViewCellPadding);
        make.left.and.right.equalTo(self);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.editSiteButtonBackground.mas_top);//.with.offset(-kTableViewCellPadding);
    }];

    // Edit  Site Button Background
    [self.editSiteButtonBackground mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.bottom.and.right.equalTo(self);
        make.height.equalTo(@54);
    }];

  // Add  Site Comments Button Background
  [self.addSiteCommentsButtonBackground mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(self.editSiteButton.mas_right);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.editSiteButton);
    make.height.equalTo(@54);
  }];

    // Edit  Site Button
    [self.editSiteButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
        make.edges.equalTo(self.editSiteButtonBackground).with.insets(padding).with.priorityHigh();
        make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(@260);
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.editSiteButtonBackground);
    }];

  // Add  Site Comments Button
  [self.addSiteCommentsButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
        make.edges.equalTo(self.addSiteCommentsButtonBackground).with.insets(padding).with.priorityHigh();
    make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(@270);
    make.top.equalTo(self.addSiteCommentsButton);
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.addSiteCommentsButtonBackground);
  }];

  // Navigation
  [self.navigationButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
      make.right.equalTo(self.mapView).with.offset(-20);
      make.bottom.equalTo(self.mapView).with.offset(-20);
  }];

}
```

How do I show the buttons side-by-side and centred at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
- (void)createConstraints {

    // Map View
    [self.mapView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.left.and.right.equalTo(self);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.mas_centerY).multipliedBy(0.9);
    }];

    // Information TextView
    [self.informationTextView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(self.mapView.mas_bottom); //.with.offset(kTableViewCellPadding);
        make.left.and.right.equalTo(self);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.editSiteButtonBackground.mas_top);//.with.offset(-kTableViewCellPadding);
    }];

    // Edit  Site Button Background
    [self.editSiteButtonBackground mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.bottom.and.right.equalTo(self);
        make.height.equalTo(@54);
    }];

  // Add  Site Comments Button Background
  [self.addSiteCommentsButtonBackground mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(self.editSiteButton.mas_right);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self);
    make.height.equalTo(@54);
  }];

    // Edit  Site Button
    [self.editSiteButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
        make.edges.equalTo(self.editSiteButtonBackground).with.insets(padding).with.priorityHigh();
        make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(@260);
        make.centerX.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(0.5);
    }];

  // Add  Site Comments Button
  [self.addSiteCommentsButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    make.edges.equalTo(self.addSiteCommentsButtonBackground).with.insets(padding).with.priorityHigh();
    make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(@260);
    make.top.equalTo(self.editSiteButton);
    make.centerX.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(1.5);
  }];

  // Navigation
  [self.navigationButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
      make.right.equalTo(self.mapView).with.offset(-20);
      make.bottom.equalTo(self.mapView).with.offset(-20);
  }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for programmatically i can not able to make clear to you, but in words if i say,

You can use drag and drop feature directly with design if it designed with storyboard or XIB.

Make "Add site comments" button as vertically centre to "Edit Site" Button and give horizontal space between both the buttons.

I hope it will help to you.

Thanks.